# Convert Flatten Json into array of json using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need to use Jolt to transform a flat JSON object into an array of JSON objects, where each row in the array corresponds to a unique index number from the original object. The output should have as many rows as there were index numbers in the original object.

**Input JSON 1**

```json
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters.location": "test",
  "batters.batter[0].id": "1001",
  "batters.batter[0].type": "Regular",
  "batters.batter[1].id": "1002",
  "batters.batter[1].type": "Chocolate"
}
```

**Output JSON 1**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters.location": "test",
    "batters.batter.id": "1001",
    "batters.batter.type": "Regular"
  },
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters.location": "test",
    "batters.batter.id": "1002",
    "batters.batter.type": "Chocolate"
  }
]
```

Another example like

**Input JSON 2**

```json
{
  "[0].id": "0001",
  "[0].type": "donut",
  "[0].name": "Cake",
  "[0].ppu": 0.55,
  "[0].batters.location": "test",
  "[0].batters.batter[0].id": "1001",
  "[0].batters.batter[0].type": "Regular",
  "[0].batters.batter[1].id": "1002",
  "[0].batters.batter[1].type": "Chocolate",
  "[1].id": "0002",
  "[1].type": "donut",
  "[1].name": "Cake2",
  "[1].ppu": 0.75,
  "[1].batters.location": "test2",
  "[1].batters.batter[0].id": "1002",
  "[1].batters.batter[0].type": "Regular",
  "[1].batters.batter[1].id": "1003",
  "[1].batters.batter[1].type": "Chocolate"
}
```

**Output JSON 2**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters.location": "test",
    "batters.batter.id": "1001",
    "batters.batter.type": "Regular"
  },
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters.location": "test",
    "batters.batter.id": "1002",
    "batters.batter.type": "Chocolate"
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake2",
    "ppu": 0.75,
    "batters.location": "test2",
    "batters.batter.id": "1002",
    "batters.batter.type": "Regular"
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake2",
    "ppu": 0.75,
    "batters.location": "test2",
    "batters.batter.id": "1003",
    "batters.batter.type": "Chocolate"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, have you checked out the previous question's answer in this while ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and it seems that it's not possible to create a flat JSON with all types of nested JSON using the given specification. Therefore, I have decided to use the FlattenJson processor in Nifi to create a flat JSON object with an index, and then use a Jolt spec to transform it into an array of JSON objects.

Comment: For this one, seems you want to get a common solution again for both types of input. It will be hard to think a complete solution but I can recommend a spec for only one type of input ... Indeed it lightens the idea for the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your both desired outputs with this single JOLT spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "\\[*\\].*\\[*\\].*": {
        "@(1,\\[&(0,1)\\]\\.id)": "[&(1,1)][&(1,3)].id",
        "@(1,\\[&(0,1)\\]\\.type)": "[&(1,1)][&(1,3)].type",
        "@(1,\\[&(0,1)\\]\\.name)": "[&(1,1)][&(1,3)].name",
        "@(1,\\[&(0,1)\\]\\.ppu)": "[&(1,1)][&(1,3)].ppu",
        "@(1,\\[&(0,1)\\]\\.batters\\.location)": "[&(1,1)][&(1,3)].batters\\.location",
        "@": "[&(1,1)][&(1,3)].&(1,2)\\.&(1,4)"
      },
      "*\\[*\\].*": {
        "@(1,id)": "[0][&(1,2)].id",
        "@(1,type)": "[0][&(1,2)].type",
        "@(1,name)": "[0][&(1,2)].name",
        "@(1,ppu)": "[0][&(1,2)].ppu",
        "@(1,batters\\.location)": "[0][&(1,2)].batters\\.location",
        "@": "[0][&(1,2)].&(1,1)\\.&(1,3)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If I want to add another nested level in json. It is not working. What needs to change in jolt spec.

"[0].batters.batter[1].abc[0].zzz": "QQQ" or
"[0].batters.batter[1].abc[0].zzz[0].www": "AAA"

Comment: @SumitManna This case has another long answer. But if you want to do it yourself you can change your code structure from `"\\[*\\].*\\[*\\].*"` with 4 variables up to 5 or 6 and create the desired output you want.

Comment: @mohemmad-reza I am using this `"\\[*\\].*\\[*\\].*\\[*\\].*"` . still, It is not working. Do I need to change any other value?

Comment: @SumitManna well done, with this change you should change all your specs. get some play with that and try to achieve your desired output

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to partition by square-bracketed integers in order to be able to loop within the upcoming reformed objects. The solution for the first input is

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*\\[*\\]*": {
        "@1,id": "&(1,2).id", // &(1,2) represents the replacement for the 2nd asterisk for the key 1 level up from the current position
        "@1,type": "&(1,2).type",
        "@1,name": "&(1,2).name",
        "@1,ppu": "&(1,2).ppu",
        "@": "&(1,2).&(1,1)&(1,3)"
      }
    }
  },
  { // repeatitions for the outer attributes are truncated
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert the JSON to the one of type array of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[#2]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the similar logic might be applied to the other input with a little bit of tweaks